# fancyBox and aspx c# integration

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, fancybox

Trying to get my head around how to integrate fancyBox with an aspx c# website.
For example where does this code go:

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
```

the Site.master page? or each individual .aspx file?

How about this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

I assume this goes in the html part:

```
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="big_image_2.jpg"><img src="small_image_2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Comment: Did you include fancybox js and css files in the `<head>` section of your document? I don't see them in your code above. Be sure you do that AFTER loading jQuery js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this between the `<head>` tags on the master page.

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>
```

I'd put this on your page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox();
    });
</script>
```

and then your link and images etc, where you need them.

Answer (score 1):

You can place it on Master page one time, and there is no problem if you do not have any fancybox class on the page.

All the script code, go on master page, the html code can be anywhere (master or other pages that use the master).

Comment: Thanks I actually did that and it works fine for images. But I cannot get it to work for links, I keep getting "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later" when I pass it a normal http link. I call it sometihng like this: <a class=various fancybox.iframe href="http:google.com">Iframe</a> Is that not the way? Same way works fine for photos.

Answer (score 1):

When you have downloaded the fancybox it comes with a bunch of samples right click on the .html page and view the source that makes you easier how to use them.

Here is the  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B36Ap/) for you

Comment: Ok got it to display. Kind of. It loads the page I want but its doing this weird thing where it then moves the page like half way out of the frame up to the point only a corner is seen. Have tried autoSize/fitToView true or false, doesn't help. I'm so close

Comment: I can see the page load up fine, then it jumps half way out of the frame. Looks like this: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/captureugp.png/ Now it doesnt do it for all sites so it might just be related to that particular site.

Comment: updated with demo check it and let me know if you still face any problems.

Comment: the photos I can get to display just fine. Having issues with a html link being displayed via IFrame. I can get it to display but it gets pushed to the corner of the popup overlay. Other sites do work just the only one I actually need seems to be problematic